# Excel dropdown: In a single cell dropdown create a list if a field is once selected cant be reselected

Tags: excel

I am creating an Excel spreadsheet for School Management, which will allow students' status to be updated. The spreadsheet is used by a variety of stakeholders. The status workflow is 1) Shortlisted, 2) Enrolled, 3) Passed, 4) Certified, and 5) Placed. It would be helpful if the user could only select "Passed" if they selected Enrolled as a status. There should be no option to select the previous or skip the dropdown.